# haproxy https health checks

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Hi I am using haproxy to load balance my https connections. I want to do active health checks however they don't seem to work. Any tips on how to correctly write the below would be welcome. I have them working fine for http port 80 connections.

```
frontend incoming_https
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  default_backend web_https

backend web_https
    mode tcp
    option httpchk GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ https://www.mysite.com
    server web-0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443 check inter 5000 port 443
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `option httpchk` in tcp mode.

You'll probably want to read up on `option ssl-hello-chk`.

Comment: Actually you can as it is described in the official documentation. You just need to add `check-ssl` parameter to `server` to force health check requests to ssl

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you *can* use option httpchk in tcp mode. Here's the necessary options to search for a string on a page behind ssl:

```
mode tcp
option httpchk GET /<URI>
http-check expect string <STRING\ WITH\ SPACES\ ESCAPED>
server <YOUR_SERVER_FQDN>:443 <YOUR_SERVER_IP>:443 check ssl verify none
```

for example, to check a login.html page for "User Name" string:

```
mode tcp
option httpchk GET /login.html
http-check expect string User\ Name
server www.example.com:443 192.168.1.1:443 check ssl verify none
```

Note that "check ssl verify none" is required and that any spaces in your search string must be escaped with a \.

Comment: this helps for the check but unfortunately browsers tell the can't establish secure connection

Comment: Found the solution. There is another `server` parameter called `check-ssl` that forces ssl on health check